# Unable to install addon extension in firefox using command line

Tags: powershell, firefox

I'm installing firefox by downloading the latest version from its website through powershell and then trying to add a required extension by using its xpi file which I downloaded from website using the below command. but I'm unable to get it added. All the other commands are working except the below one. It is just opening an empty browser without adding extension to it. Please share your thoughts how to get it done using powershell.

.\firefox.exe -install-global-extension "C:\foo\modify_header_value_http_headers-0.1.3-an+fx.xpi"

for reference used below site too.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error on your console?

Comment: Negative @Seth . There are no error's. Once I fire the above command, the expected behavior is to add that extension but observed behavior is, new Firefox browser pop's up.